# AWS RDS : Delete Protection or Snapshot on instance level through cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I have enabled `DeleteProtection` and `DeletionPolicy` Snapshot but from Cloud formation it only possible from cluster level not instance level.

My problem if any how any instance of the cluster will removed how can I get back all its tables, data back if I am not able to take snapshot of instance level from cloud formation. And `DeleteProtection` also not possible in instance level as well.

Any help will really appreciable..

For DeletionPolicy Snapshot got below error

> DeletionPolicy:Snapshot cannot be specified for a cluster instance, use deletion policy on the cluster instead."

Comment: I would assume that if you enable `DeletionProtection` and `DeletionPolicy` at cluster level, they would apply to all instances in that cluster. Is that not the case? Or are you looking to have different policies for different instances in that cluster?

Comment: Cluster Level we applied but unfortunately we saw our instances are gone and no tables, schemas are present after tat

Comment: Have you tried with an `UpdateReplacePolicy` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html?